# Need a tiny, light html editor for web

Tags: javascript, html, editor

As the title says, I am searching a very tiny rich text editor. Every editor I've seen is big and has too many features. All I need is buttons to make text bold, italic, set the font of text, set the style to a paragraph or a heading and to add/edit links. I won't have a big library for that.

I think I will need to change it a bit. I have to integrate an image upload (already existing) as a feature to add and resize images in the content.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/ It has a simple editor mode, might solve your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out:

[TinyEditor](https://github.com/jessegreathouse/TinyEditor)

> TinyEditor is a simple JavaScript WYSIWYG editor that is **both
>   lightweight (8KB) and standalone**. It can easily be customized to
>   integrate with any website through CSS and the multitude of
>   parameters. It handles most of the **basic formatting needs** and has some
>   functionality built in to help keep the rendered markup as clean as
>   possible.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you using bootstrap. Consider to use summernote.

Super Simple WYSIWYG Editor on Bootstrap.

http://summernote.org

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're looking for.   Do you need WYSIWYG?  If not, I've had success using markitup:

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

Comment: I think I won't make it too complicate for my customers to edit their texts. Most of them would paste content from word, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)?

Comment: This is nearly 1 MB.. I want a light and small without these superfluous features I don't need...

Comment: If you don't use every feature I believe you can cut down the size

Comment: Looking at the download, the plugins directory is 1.25 MB.

Comment: I know Magento successfully uses TinyMCE without conflicting with Prototype nor loading any other libraries. So this is definitely plausible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap try [Bootstrap-WYSIWYG](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/)

Comment: (Has no support for IE < v.10.)

Answer (score 0):

How about [bootstrap-editor](https://github.com/trantorLiu/bootstrap-editor)?
It's simple and beautiful. It extends [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) with file-uploading feature (by using [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)).